# Force "2005" for ProviderManifestToken in EF Data Model

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Every time I update my data model, it makes this value 2008, breaking the 2005 server deployment.  Is their anything besides a build action I can use to stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you connect to a 2005 DB/server when you update, then it will stay at 2005. That, or manual editing, are the only ways I know.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [MSBuild.Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/), I added a BeforeBuild Target that uses the XmlUpdate task to always change the ProviderManifestToken to 2005, in case someone changed it by updating the data model.

Here is the BeforeBuild Target:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<XmlUpdate Prefix="ssdl"
            Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl"
            XPath="//ssdl:Schema/@ProviderManifestToken"
            XmlFileName="Model.edmx"
            Value="2005"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this question because I needed to prevent the EDMX from upgrading to Sql Server 2012 (from 2008). I also used [MSBuild.CommunityTasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks), but used a slightly more generic XPath expression to avoid using the namespace (which has changed from what's shown in jnosek's answer):

```
    <XmlUpdate XmlFileName="Orders\Model.edmx" 
            XPath="//*[local-name() = 'Schema']/@ProviderManifestToken"
            Value="2008"/>
```